# Toggle button to change the background color of the layout of the android app

Tags: java, android, togglebutton

Toggle button to change the background color of the layout of the Android app

I am trying to add a toggle button on the android studio that can change the background color of the app layout

```java
    public void perform_action(View v) {
        g = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
        g.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    RelativeLayout currentLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
                    currentLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                } else {
                    RelativeLayout currentLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
                    currentLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

the expected result is the background change however this is not happening and the app crashes after this

Comment: can you show us your error log ?

Comment: What is your `crash` report?

Comment: 10519-10519/com.example.crt D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
 10519-10519/com.example.crt E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.crt, PID: 10519
    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout
        at com.example.crt.MainActivity$2.onCheckedChanged(MainActivity.java:94)
        at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:171)
        at android.widget.ToggleButton.setChecked(ToggleButton.java:71)
        at android.widget.CompoundButton.toggle(CompoundButto

Comment: Maybe you are using `ConstraintLayout` in the XML file but you are initializing `RelativeLayout` in the java file. You have to use the same layout. Can you give us the XML file code?

Comment: changed the layout to constraint and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please use Constraint layout here 
`RelativeLayout currentLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);` instead of RelativeLayout because you use constraint layout in your XML file ;)

Answer (score 0):

According to your `crush` report: You are using `ConstraintLayout` in the XML file. On the other hand, you are initializing `RelativeLayout` in the Java file.

You have to use the same layout at the same time in both files. So change your XML file layout into `RelativeLayout` Instead of `ConstraintLayout` or change `ConstraintLayout` in the Java file `ConstraintLayout` of RelativeLayout.

Just keep in your mind **Both Layouts should be the same.**

Hope it will help you.

Thank you

Comment: It's my pleasure if you got the help from me.

Answer (score 0):

Once i changed to layout to Constraint it worked fine.

```
if (isChecked) {
                ConstraintLayout currentLayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
                currentLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            } else {
                ConstraintLayout currentLayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
                currentLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
```